# EMGU 3.0.0 OpenCV Insert and Remove Contour Points

Tags: c#, emgucv

I recently tried upgrading my Emgu libraries from 2.4.2 to 3.0.0. So there have been significant changes in the version, and I am having a bit of trouble modifying the code to make it work.

The 2.4.2 version of Emgu had a Contour Class: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/do ... Index.html

My code uses that, and sometimes I remove points using the RemoveAt method or add points using the Insert method.  My initial contour could contain points that are outliers (due to various criteria, such as curvature, distance between adjacent points, etc.)

What I tried to do in the new version of Emgu was use the VectorOfPoint class. It works for much of my code, but it still does not have (as far as I can tell) any equivalent of RemoveAt method. It seems to have something similar to the Insert method (Push method: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/9f6838b0-d946-adc6-e14e-8f223079f5e3.htm) though I am not sure that it is exactly what I want.

I looked into the matter a bit further, and saw that the Mat class has a **PushBack** and **PopBack** method, which allows you to add and remove an element at the end of a sequence.  However, as I had the code before, I was removing elements at certain places (the **RemoveAt** method allows you to input the index i of the element to be removed).

As an example, this is how I used the RemoveAt method before:

```
for (int i = nPoints - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (!goodPoint[i])
                    {
                        shapeContour.RemoveAt(i);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
```

I do not see a direct function I can use in the new version of Emgu.  Am I mistaken?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? [ask] You should add your relevant code to the question, and also add tags for the programming language and relevant libraries you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a value from a VectorOfPoint you use pop() (removes and retrieves the value from the end of the vector) ,
ther is no "remove by index" method but obviously you can build your own using pop() and push()(insert to the end of the vector).

Comment: So looking at the VectorOfPoint class, I do not see a **Pop()** method, but just a **Push()** method: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/05a55c58-b440-ca74-439c-f288410e692f.htm

Am I better off finding my "good" points and then creating a new VectorOfPoint object, whereby I insert only the "good" points?

Comment: List points = new List<Point>(vec.toArray()); points.removeAt(i)....points.add(x)....     VectorOfPoints vec2 = new VectorOfPoints(points.toArray());

Comment: You can build a function that executes the code above, even better for you is to create an extension method for VectorOfPoint (a static method with first parameter as "this VectorOfPoint".